# How I can fix error in android file in vs code?

Tags: java, android, gradle, visual-studio-code

[image: 1]

it is showing:
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip'.
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
You can try some of the following options:

- changing the IDE settings.
- changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
- changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below to install **Java11** in VS code.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> open command palette
2. search and select **Java: Configure Java Runtime**
   [image]
3. Click **download** to download other versions
   [image]
4. Select **Java11** in the new window, then click the **Download** button to start the download
   [image]
5. Your default browser will open and start downloading Java 11
   [image]
6. After the download is complete, run the file to start the installation
   [image]
7. After the installation is complete, click the **Reload Window** at the bottom of the picture shown in ***step 4*** to restart VS Code
8. Select **Java11** in the drop down options
   [image]